# Javascript Error: product_info_tabsJsTabs is not defined

Tags: javascript, magento, magento-1.5

I am getting this error: “`product_info_tabsJsTabs is not defined`” in my Magento v1.5.1 install.

What this does: not allow the user in the admin panel to add or edit a product. I can edit/create categories and attributes, but not products.

These are the steps I have taken so far:

1. tailed my php log file - no errors
2. turned on the Magento debugger - no new entries in exception.log and system.log
3. i compared the Magento admin files with the ones from another install currently working - they look the same; however, there may be some add-ons that produce the javascript interference.

Has anyone encountered this and found a solution?

Edit - JS Errors come from app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/js.phtml

`// bind active tab

if(product_info_tabsJsTabs && product_info_tabsJsTabs.activeTab && $('store_switcher'))
{  $('store_switcher').switchParams = 'active_tab/'+product_info_tabsJsTabs.activeTab.name+'/';
}`

and from app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit.phtml

`Product.AttributesBridge.setTabsObject(product_info_tabsJsTabs);`

I will add the body of the files once I figure out how to format it in a human-readable fashion.

Comment: Not enough information. At least show the relevant files, and any other relevant information, such as browser vendor and version.

Comment: using firefox 7

files:
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit.phtml,

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php

Comment: If you could post the code, or provide us with a link, we may be able to find your error. By the sounds of it, a crucial variable is not being defined.

Comment: code is too big to post in this section; is there a tag that allows me to post more characters? plus, i highly doubt that the error is in the files, since the same code works for one of my other installs. the problem is most probably related to javascript interference from some extension, but i cannot figure out which.

Comment: At the bottom of your question, there's a edit link. Use it to edit your answer.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else way having this issue and it wasn't fixed by any of the above answers, mine error was caused by the [Mage world - loyalty points pro extension](http://www.mage-world.com/magento-reward-points-pro-extension.html).

It was caused by an expired development key, once I renewed the license key, all was well. Alternatively you could disable to plugin by following the same steps as Alexey Shein provided.

I will report this issue to their development team to see if they can fix it so others may not have this issue in the future.

Until then, I hope this helps anyone else who came about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem. In our case it was a PDF module that was the problem. After installing "Product PDF Brochure" we had the same issue. We couldn't add/edit any products anymore.

We uninstalled this module and everything was working properly.

Greets

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It was caused by AW_Sarp module. We disabled it in System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Modules. The problem has gone after full disabling in app/etc/modules/AW_Sarp.xml.

Hope it helps.